# Angular promises and errors

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, angular-promise

I'm a bit confused how to chain promises in AngularJS. I have a `$resource` implementation... This is some simplified code to get my point:

```
myResource
    .save({ id: 123 })
    .$promise
    .then(function(data) {
        // redirect to root on success
        $location.url("/");
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("Failed");
    })
    .finally(function() {
        // reenable form
        $scope.enabled = true;
    })
```

What I'm confused about is whether my `.catch()` function will be called when my resource will fail saving or will it only catch errors that would originate in `.then()` function or maybe both?

When chaining these how can I have a single `.catch` (before `.finally`) that would catch all errors of calls that happened in the chain proceeding it?

> Note: I'm aware I could provide the success and error functions in `.save` function but I have other parts to handle as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, read the docs of [Angular's implementation of promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Promises can be resolved in two ways - either successful (the `resolve` method) or not (the `reject` method).

When resource could not be saved (i.e. server did not respond with 2XX status), then your catch method will be called, as the promise will be rejected.

Also please note, that your `catch` handler should reject the promise for next possible handlers. When you return non-rejected value from your catch method, it is assumed that the error has been handled and the promise can call subsequent `then` methods, if any. Therefore, if there is any possibility that the promise is used somewhere else, your code should look like this:

```
// inject $q
myResource
.save({ id: 123 })
.$promise
.then(function(data) {
    // redirect to root on success
    $location.url("/");
})
.catch(function() {
    console.log("Failed");
    return $q.reject();
})
.finally(function() {
    // reenable form
    $scope.enabled = true;
})
```

Also notice that you made a typo in the `then` method - you wrote "ulr" instead of "url".

Comment: I did read the docs, but things aren't as clear as one would expect (as I find quite usual with Angular docs - not that they'd be invalid, but they are sometimes missing critical details). What I was mostly looking for was whether it makes any difference where `.catch` calls are positioned in relation to `.then`s? And the end result (I've made several tests) is that every `.catch` covers everything proceeding it up to last previous `.catch` if there was any. ...while also depending on resolved/rejected states being reported before it.